# Сравнение и вывод атрибутов в WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Спрашивал про связывание простых товаров по цветам, никто не помог. Зайдем с другой стороны.

Интернет-магазин на WooCommerce. Есть необходимость разбить вариативные товары на простые (у каждого свой URL), после чего связать их по цветам. Задаем одинаковым товарам одну и ту же модель в атрибуте (model), но разные значения цвета на каждый (cvet). Достаем значение атрибута model, ищем все товары с таким же значением, находим, выбираем и выводим на карточку товара все цвета, найденные в базе, точно такой же модели, со ссылками на другие карточки товаров.

Звучит вроде не так сложно, но возможно ли такое сделать? Спасибо.

Comment: Возможно. Алгоритм описан. Сложность вы сильно недооцениваете )

Comment: Не подскажете как?))

Comment: Этот вопрос (в котором много подвопросов) выходит далеко за рамки StackOverflow. Вам лучше нанять фрилансера.